# Add a class to an image in Hexo.io

Tags: hexo

I would like to add classes to images in Hexo.io posts. 
Can someone explain how to do it using this syntax in Hexo.io ?

{% asset_img pic.jpg This is the image title %}

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question
{% asset_img 'className' 'pic.jpg' 'This is the image title' %}